# Fast Linq operation on list of file names

Tags: c#, string, performance, list, linq

I have tens of thousands of files that have a filename format:

```
public static string mTimeFormat = "yyyyMMdd_HHmmss_fff__N";
```

where N could be anything from 1 to a big number (lets say 1,000,000).

Those are the file names enumerated in a sub-folder - please don't ask me how and why - it is an existing project - it works and its fast. The N number **had to be added** just now. This breaks the fast retrieval of range of files that was originally done by:

```
// retrieve range of file names
string t1 = startTime.ToString(mTimeFormat);
string t2 = endTime.ToString(mTimeFormat);
List<string> results = fileNameList.FindAll(s => (String.Compare(s, t1, true) > 0) && (String.Compare(s, t2, true) < 0));
```

In order to keep the existing code working (which is fast) I need to strip "__N"
the the filenames in order to keep the fast retrieval of filename range.
I tried iterating through the list but it is not fast enough...Any suggestion for Linq operation that will strip "__N" from each and every file name in one fast operation?

Comment: What is the code that is not fast enough?

Comment: A simple iteration where you find an index of "__N" and take the substring of it adding it to a new list...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the end-part "could be anything" the first part should be fixed so just taking the substring from there should be fine. LINQ however will not bring a speed benefit probably as it is iterating over the list internally as well. This code however might be worth a try:

```
var lengthOfFirstPart = "yyyyMMdd_HHmmss_fff".Length;
fileNameList = fileNameList
               .Select(f=>f.SubString(0, lengthOfFirstPart)
               .ToList(); // assuming it was a List<string> before
```